# how work with jpeg in python2.7 win64 without PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I cant run jpeg support in PIL and think about another modules for python...

i have: Win7 x64 + Python 2.7 x64
and PIL says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\arduino\pde\freezelight_printer\freezelight_printer_computer.py", line 43, in <module>
    print im.getpixel((x,y))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 949, in getpixel
    self.load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 189, in load
    d = Image._getdecoder(self.mode, d, a, self.decoderconfig)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 385, in _getdecoder
    raise IOError("decoder %s not available" % decoder_name)
IOError: decoder jpeg not available
```

is there an alternative PIL in python? I whant read pixel data from jpeg. Nothing else... But all what i find is PIL and imageMagic. First not worked. Second - its not python module and need install to system some programs...

is there something simple for read pixel data from jpeg without compilation, installing visual studio and other programs?

Comment: Why you don't post the code to see where is the error using pil?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.1.0) fork of PIL.

You'll find binary installers on PyPi, so you don't need to compile anything yourself.